# How to Convert an Alphanumeric (Reference) Number Containing a Decimal Point to a String in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a reference number of the following type DAA76647.1 which I want to convert unchanged to a string in Mathematica.

That is

myfn[DAA76647.1]

gives as output

"DAA76647.1"

Is there an easy way to do this? (The input cannot be a string and, other than conversion to a string, I do not want to change the input in any other way).

**Update**

```
ToString /@ {A1234, 1234.1, A1234 .5}
```

gives the following output (where I have simply entered everything from the keyboard)

```
{"A1234", "1234.1", "0.5 A1234"}
```

It appears that if what goes before the decimal point is alphanumeric, there is a problem.

**Possible Workaround**

Based on a suggested solution by [David Carraher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/638130/david-carraher), a possible method is as follows:

```
ToString[# /.a_ b_ :> ToString[b] <> StringDrop[ToString[a], 1]] & /@ {A1234, 
  1234.1, A1234 .5}
```

giving as output:

```
{"A1234", "1234.1", "A1234.5"}
```

This seems to work OK provided that what comes after the decimal point is not alphanumeric, and provided that what comes before does not begin with zero (0A123.1, for example).

If alphanumerics occur only after the decimal point, this may be incorporated

```
StringReplace[ToString[123.45 B55c], Whitespace -> ""]
```

but if alphanumerics occur before and after the decimal point the number still needs to be entered as a string.

**David Carraher's original suggestion**

```
f[Times[a_, b_]] := ToString[b] <> ToString[a]
```

Comment: Where is the input coming from?

Comment: @Michael.  The number is the accession number for a database, and I want it to form part of a _string_ I generate to Import from the database. I don't want the requirement that the user must input a string (it will possibly be a cut-and-paste). (Other unique identifers, such as  GI : 8375436 are easy to handle, but I want to give a choice).

Comment: @TomD I think Michael's question is: in what format does DAA76647.1 come?  I assumed (below) that it was entered directly from the keyboard.

Comment: Directly from the keyboard within a mma notebook is OK (but not as a string)

Comment: But how are they entering the input via keyboard or copy/paste? Are you using an input field? A placeholder? Pasting directly into a cell? If you don't keep the input as a string, there are myriad ways to break your code because of the way the parser will attempt to interpret the input as an expression.

Comment: @Michael.  I don't think there is any confusion.  I am entering via the keyboard and I want to convert to a string.  `ToString[A1234]`, `ToString[1234.5]` work as expected but `ToString[A1234 .5]` dosen't. I am not prepared to enter as a string. This may be tedious if I have many such numbers. I want to convert. (I can of course assemble a list of such numbers in a word processor such as Word and Import (giving strings), but that seems crazy.

Comment: Call it a failure of imagination if you must, but why would you ever need to do `ToString /@ {A1234, 1234.1, A1234 .5}` (and get the output you want)?  It looks like an import problem to me.

Comment: I was merely highlighting the difference. The number is a reference number (DNA sequence as it so happens) which I want to use to Import from a database. I do not want to input as a string, but of course I could do (I may have 5000 such numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter  `DAA76647DAA76647.1` via an input cell in a Mma notebook, Mma will interpret the characters as a multiplication. It even automatically inserts a space between the 7 and the .1 (at least in Mma 8) when you input it.

```
DAA76647DAA76647 .1 // FullForm

(*Out= Times[0.1`,DAA76647DAA76647] *)
```

This looks promising:

```
f[Times[a_, b_]] := ToString[b] <> ToString[a]
```

---

**EDIT**: 
However, as TomD noted (and I somehow missed), it adds an additional zero to the solution!

```
f[Times[DAA76647DAA76647 .1]]
(*Out= DAA76647DAA766470.1  *)

%//FullForm
"DAA76647DAA766470.1"
```

TomD later showed how it is possible to handle this by `StringDrop`ping the zero.

This corrected solution will work if only numbers appear to the right of the decimal point and if the left-hand part is not interpreted as a product.

If you try to enter `DAA76647.01A` Mma will parse it as

```
(*Out= Times[".01",A,DAA76647]    *)
```

Notice that it changes the order of the components.

I cannot see a way to handle this reordering.

Comment: @David. The problem I'm having is that `ToString` will not do what I want.  With mma7 (on a Mac) I get "0.1 DAA76647" as output. Perhaps I am doing something stupid?

Comment: @David.  Thanks for your answer.  I am sorry to persist on this one, but your very nice approach also inserts an extra zero before the decimal point. The number is an accession number (see above).  I would also like the soln to be as general as possible and handle DAA766.1A4, for example. (It is the decimal point that is causing me the trouble).

Comment: @TomD  Can we assume that the data were keyboard-entered in a Mma notebook input cell?

Comment: Hmm.  This is considerably more difficult than I had originally imagined!

Comment: @David.  It would seem that using `StringDrop` in conjunction with your original suggestion provides a possible workaround. If you think so, maybe you could repost the method as part of your reply? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @TomD Thanks. I reposted the original suggestion.  Yes, `StringDrop` gets rid of the nasty zero.  I wouldn't try to sell the solution to the Librarian in Chief of the British Library, but it's a nice start.

Answer (score 3):

The call for `myfn[DAA76647.1]` should be intercepted at the stage of converting Input to an expression.

You can see that Input has the form `RowBox[{"myfn", "[", RowBox[{"DAA76647", ".1"}], "]"}]`:

```
In[1]:= myfn[DAA76647 .1]
DownValues[InString]

Out[1]= myfn[0.1 DAA76647]

Out[2]= {HoldPattern[InString[1]] :> 
  ToString[RowBox[{"myfn", "[", RowBox[{"DAA76647", ".1"}], "]"}], 
   InputForm], 
 HoldPattern[InString[2]] :> 
  ToString[RowBox[{"DownValues", "[", "InString", "]"}], InputForm]}
```

We could create a special case definition for `MakeExpression`:

```
MakeExpression[RowBox[{"myfn", "[", RowBox[{"DAA76647", ".1"}], "]"}],
   f_] := MakeExpression[RowBox[{"myfn", "[", "\"DAA76647.1\"", "]"}],
   f]
```

You can see that now `myfn[DAA76647 .1]` works as desired:

```
In[4]:= myfn[DAA76647 .1]//FullForm
Out[4]//FullForm= myfn["DAA76647.1"]
```

This approach can be generalized to something like

```
MakeExpression[RowBox[{"myfn", "[", expr:Except[_String], "]"}], form_] := 
 With[{mexpr = StringJoin[expr /. RowBox -> List]}, Hold[myfn[mexpr]]]
myfn[expr_String] := (* what ever you want to do here *)
```

Note that the `Except[_String]` part is not really needed... since the following code won't do anything wrong with a String.
At the moment, the code only works with simple examples with one-dimensional box structure. If you want something that handles more general input, you might want to add error checking or extra rules for things like `SuperscriptBox` and friends. Or hit it with the hammer of `Evaluate[Alternatives @@ Symbol /@ Names["*Box"]] -> List` to make all Box objects become lists and flatten everything down.

Comment: I don't know if you made your answer a CW because you wanted people to edit it or not... but anyway - I made the generalization that you alluded to!

Comment: @Simon Thank you. I made my answer CW because I had troubles with generalization and need help with this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can directly type this between the brackets of a function call, but would

```
myfn[InputString[]]
```

work for you?

Comment: @ Sjoerd.  This comes close, and is probably the way to go. It looks as though I'll have to input as a string (or use a word processor to assemble a large list, and then import). Many thanks for this (and for previous help)