# When does Mathematica create a new Symbol?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Good day,

I thought earlier that *Mathematica* creates new symbols in the current `$Context` at the stage of converting of the input string (that is assigned to `InString`) to input expression (that is assigned to `In`). But one simple example has broken this explanation:

```
In[1]:= ?f
During evaluation of In[1]:= Information::notfound: Symbol f not found. >>
In[2]:= Names["`*"]
Out[2]= {}
In[3]:= DownValues[In]//First
InString[1]
Names["`*"]
Out[3]= HoldPattern[In[1]]:>Information[f,LongForm->False]
Out[4]= \(? f\)
Out[5]= {}
```

You can see that there is no symbol `f` in the `$ContextPath` although it is already used inside definition for `In[1]`.

This example shows that it is in principle possible in *Mathematica* to make definitions with symbols that do not exist in the `$ContextPath` without creating them. This could be interesting alternative to the method of avoiding symbol creation using `Symbol`:

```
In[9]:= ff := Symbol["f"]
Names["`*"]
Out[10]= {"ff"}
```

Can anybody explain at which conditions and at which stage of the evaluation process *Mathematica* creates new Symbols?

### **EDIT**

As Sasha have noticed in the comment to this question, in really I was spoofed by default `ShowStringCharacters->False` settings for the Output cells in the default stylesheet Core.nb and missed the `FullForm` of the output for `DownValues[In]//First`. In really symbol `f` is not used in the definition for `In[1]` as we can see also by using `InputForm`:

```
In[1]:= ?f
DownValues[In]//First//InputForm
During evaluation of In[1]:= Information::notfound: Symbol f not found. >>
Out[2]//InputForm=
HoldPattern[In[1]] :> Information["f", LongForm -> False]
```

Sorry for hasty statement.

So the question now is just about the stage at which *Mathematica* decides to create new `Symbol` and how we can prevent it?
For example, in the above example we input `f` as `Symbol` but *Mathematica* converts it to `String` without creating new symbol. This is built-in behavior of `MakeExpression`:

```
In[1]:= ?f
InputForm[MakeExpression[ToExpression@InString[1], StandardForm]]

During evaluation of In[1]:= Information::notfound: Symbol f not found. >>

Out[2]//InputForm=
HoldComplete[Information["f", LongForm -> False]]
```

Probably it is possible to define some type of syntactic construct that will prevent symbol creation until the evaluation time.

### About stage of evaluation when new symbol is created

We can see that incrementing `$Line` happens before calling `MakeExpression` but new `Symbol` creation and assigning new value for `InString` and `In` variables happens after calling `MakeExpression`:

```
In[1]:= MakeExpression[My`boxes_,My`f_]/;!TrueQ[My`$InsideMakeExpression]:=Block[{My`$InsideMakeExpression=True},Print[$Line];Print[DownValues[InString][[All,1]]];Print[DownValues[In][[All,1]]];Print[Names["`*"]];MakeExpression[My`boxes,My`f]];
In[2]:= a
During evaluation of In[2]:= 2
During evaluation of In[2]:= {HoldPattern[InString[1]]}
During evaluation of In[2]:= {HoldPattern[In[1]]}
During evaluation of In[2]:= {}
Out[2]= a
```

The same we can say about [`$PreRead`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626387/how-to-intercept-assigning-new-value-for-the-in-variable/5626503#5626503) and `$NewSymbol` call time:

```
In[1]:= $NewSymbol:=Print["Names[\"`*\"]=",Names["`*"],"\nDownValues[InString]=",DownValues[InString][[All,1]],"\nDownValues[In]=",DownValues[In][[All,1]],"\nName: ",#1,"\tContext: ",#2]&
In[2]:= a
During evaluation of In[2]:= Names["`*"]={}
DownValues[InString]={HoldPattern[InString[1]]}
DownValues[In]={HoldPattern[In[1]]}
Name: a Context: Global`
Out[2]= a
```

`$Pre` executes *after* new assignment to `In` is made and *after* creating all new `Symbol`s in the current `$Context`:

```
In[1]:= $Pre := (Print[Names["`*"]]; 
   Print[DownValues[In][[All, 1]]]; ##) &

In[2]:= a

During evaluation of In[2]:= {a}

During evaluation of In[2]:= {HoldPattern[In[1]],HoldPattern[In[2]]}

Out[2]= a
```

It seems that [it is not possible to intercept assigning new value for `In` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626387/how-to-intercept-assigning-new-value-for-the-in-variable/5626503#5626503).

---

The conclusion: new `Symbol`s are created after calling `$PreRead`, `MakeExpression` and `$NewSymbol` but before calling `$Pre`.

Comment: Doing DownValues[In] // First // FullForm I see 
RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[In[1]],Information["f",Rule[LongForm,False]]]

Comment: @Sasha You are right, I missed `FullForm`. It means that in really symbol `f` is not used inside definition for `In` as I thought before. But could you comment is my understanding of symbol creation (described at the first paragraph of the question) right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your question in the *edit* part:  not sure if this is what you had in mind , but in FrontEnd sessions you can use `$PreRead` to keep symbols as strings during the parsing stage. Here is one possible hack which does it:

```
symbolQ = StringMatchQ[#, RegularExpression["[a-zA-Z$][a-zA-Z$`0-9]*"]] &;

ClearAll[keepSymbolsAsStrings];
SetAttributes[keepSymbolsAsStrings, HoldAllComplete];

$PreRead  = # //. RowBox[{"keepSymbolsAsStrings", rest___}] :>
 RowBox[{"keepSymbolsAsStrings", 
   Sequence @@ ({rest} //. x_String?symbolQ :>
       With[{context = Quiet[Context[x]]},            
        StringJoin["\"", x, "\""] /; 
         Head[context] === Context])}] &;
```

The symbol will be converted to string only if it does not exist yet (which is checked via `Context[symbol_string_name]`). For example

```
In[4]:= keepSymbolsAsStrings[a+b*Sin[c]]//FullForm

Out[4]//FullForm= keepSymbolsAsStrings[Plus["a",Times["b",Sin["c"]]]]
```

It is important that the `keepSymbolsAsStrings` is defined first, so that this symbol is created. This makes it re-entrant:

```
In[6]:= keepSymbolsAsStrings[a+b*Sin[c]*keepSymbolsAsStrings[d+e*Sin[f]]]//FullForm

Out[6]//FullForm= 
  keepSymbolsAsStrings[Plus["a",Times["b",Sin["c"],
  keepSymbolsAsStrings[Plus["d",Times["e",Sin["f"]]]]]]]
```

Now, you can  handle these symbols (kept as strings) after your code has been parsed, in the way you like. You could also use a different `symbolQ` function - I just use a simple-minded one for the sake of example.

This won't work for packages though. I don't see a straightforward way to do this for packages. One simplistic approach would be to dynamically redefine `Needs`, to modify the source on the string level in a similar manner as a sort of a pre-processing stage, and effectively call `Needs` on the modified source. But string-level source modifications are generally fragile.

HTH

**Edit**

The above code has a flaw in that it is hard to distinguish which strings were meant to be strings and which were symbols converted by the above function. You can modify the code above by changing `ClearAll[keepSymbolsAsStrings]` to `ClearAll[keepSymbolsAsStrings, symbol]` and `StringJoin["\"", x, "\""]` by `RowBox[{"symbol", "[", StringJoin["\"", x, "\""], "]"}]` to keep track of which strings in the resulting expression correspond to converted symbols.

**Edit 2**

Here is the modified code, based on `MakeExpression` rather than `$PreRead`, as suggested by @Alexey:

```
symbolQ =  StringMatchQ[#, RegularExpression["[a-zA-Z$][a-zA-Z$0-9`]*"]] &;

ClearAll[keepSymbolsAsStrings, symbol];
SetAttributes[keepSymbolsAsStrings, HoldAllComplete];

Module[{tried},
 MakeExpression[RowBox[{"keepSymbolsAsStrings", rest___}], form_] :=
  Block[{tried = True},
    MakeExpression[
       RowBox[{"keepSymbolsAsStrings", 
         Sequence @@ ({rest} //. x_String?symbolQ :>
            With[{context = Quiet[Context[x]]},            
             RowBox[{"symbol", "[", StringJoin["\"", x, "\""], "]"}] /;
             Head[context] === Context])}], form]
  ] /;!TrueQ[tried]
]
```

We need the [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656)  of Todd Gayley to break from an infinite recursion in definitions of `MakeExpression`. Here are the examples again:

```
In[7]:= keepSymbolsAsStrings[a+b*Sin[c]]//FullForm

Out[7]//FullForm= keepSymbolsAsStrings[Plus[symbol["a"],Times[symbol["b"],Sin[symbol["c"]]]]]

In[8]:= keepSymbolsAsStrings[a+b*Sin[c]*keepSymbolsAsStrings[d+e*Sin[f]]]//FullForm

Out[8]//FullForm=  keepSymbolsAsStrings[Plus[symbol["a"],Times[symbol["b"],Sin[symbol["c"]],
keepSymbolsAsStrings[Plus[symbol["d"],Times[symbol["e"],Sin[symbol["f"]]]]]]]]
```

This method is cleaner since `$PreRead` is still available to the end user.

Comment: Thank you for this clever solution! But probably the method with making a new definition for `MakeExpression` could generate the same overhead while leaving `$PreRead` free for a user.

Comment: Indeed, using `MakeExpression` sounds like a cleaner alternative, if you can make it work (I didn't try), especially if you are not the end user.

Comment: As I see from Simon's edit of my [recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597281/how-to-convert-an-alphanumeric-reference-number-containing-a-decimal-point-to-a/5602084#5602084) the primary undocumented cause of problems with `MakeExpression` is that it must return a `Hold*` expression.

Comment: @Alexey  Thanks for the link, pretty interesting. I had an impression that normally `MakeExpression` wraps the result in `HoldComplete` rather than `Hold`.  Anyways, I have updated my code accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`$NewSymbol`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24NewSymbol.html) and [`$NewMessage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24NewMessage.htm) to have a better understanding when the symbol is created. But from the virtual book, the symbol is created in `$Context` when it can be found in neither `$Context` nor `$ContextPath`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your basic understanding that symbols are created when the input is parsed into an expression is correct.

The subtle part is that `?` at the beginning of a line (and `<<` and `>>`) parse specially to allow strings without requiring quotation marks.  (The implicit strings here are patterns like `*Min*` for `?` and file names for `<<` and `>>`.)