# How to intercept assigning new value for the In variable?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I wish to intercept assigning new values for the `In` variable.

I have tried to do this by defining `UpValues` for `In` but it does not help in this case:

```
Unprotect[In];
In /: Set[In[line_], expr_] /; ! TrueQ[$InsideSet] := 
 Block[{$InsideSet = True}, 
  Print[HoldForm@HoldForm[expr]; Set[In[line], expr]]]
In /: SetDelayed[In[line_], expr_] /; ! TrueQ[$InsideSet] := 
 Block[{$InsideSet = True}, 
  Print[HoldForm@HoldForm[expr]; SetDelayed[In[line], expr]]]
```

Is it possible to intercept it?

P.S. This question has arisen as a part of [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616966/when-mathematica-creates-new-symbol) on the stage when *Mathematica* creates new `Symbol`s.

### EDIT

I would wish to intercept explicitly the assignment new DownValue for the `In` variable. `$Pre` executes *after* this assignment and *after* creating all new `Symbol`s in the current `$Context`:

```
In[1]:= $Pre := (Print[Names["`*"]]; 
   Print[DownValues[In][[All, 1]]]; ##) &

In[2]:= a

During evaluation of In[2]:= {a}

During evaluation of In[2]:= {HoldPattern[In[1]],HoldPattern[In[2]]}

Out[2]= a
```

Comment: What symbols are you trying to prevent being created?  If you pose what you really want to do, maybe someone will have a nice solution for that.  I don't see trying to hook into `In` having a productive outcome.

Comment: @Brett My goals are primarily exploratory at this moment. I am just trying to collect the most powerful instruments for analysis and control of the evaluation.

Comment: One approach which allows in some cases to have a greater control over the evaluation is to construct custom evaluators on top of Mathematica's evaluator. This may induce a significant overhead, but that is a price for flexibility. One example I posted in this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/e9e7551253d39031 (may have bugs). In some cases, `Stack` can be used to get evaluation that is otherwise hard or impossible to implement: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/1982c4a8024e6c84

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [`$Pre`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24Pre.html) and [`$PreRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24PreRead.html)?

`$Pre` is a global variable whose value, if set, is applied to every input expression.

`$PreRead` is a global variable whose value, if set, is applied to the text or box form of every input expression before it is fed to Mathematica.

**UPDATE** (now with *better* example)

```
In[1]:= $Pre = 
  Function[{x}, Print["In[",$Line,"] is: ", Unevaluated[x]]; x, HoldFirst];

In[2]:= 2 + 2

During evaluation of In[2]:= In[2] is: 2+2

Out[2]= 4

In[3]:= InString[2]

During evaluation of In[3]:= In[3] is: InString[2]

Out[3]= "\\(2 + 2\\)"
```

**UPDATE 2**

Replace `$Pre` with `$PreRead` in my code above and you get close to what you want, I believe:

```
In[1]:= $PreRead = Function[{x}, Print[Names["`*"]]; x, HoldFirst]

Out[1]= Function[{x}, Print[Names["`*"]]; x, HoldFirst]

In[2]:= a = 1

During evaluation of In[2]:= {x}

Out[2]= 1

In[3]:= b = 2

During evaluation of In[3]:= {a,x}

Out[3]= 2
```

It's not possible to intercept `In` at the `*Value` level because the Kernel is simply not interacting with `In` via value manipulation in "top-level" Mathematica code.

Comment: Thank you for the point! But this question is about intercepting assignments to `In`.

Comment: `$Pre` and `$PreRead` can be used to do that, I updated with an example. If you just want to snoop, you can make `$Pre` return the argument unchanged, after you inspect it.

Comment: @Michael Please see EDITed part in my question.

Comment: Also, you can use `$Line` to know which In value is going to be set.

Comment: It seems that you are right: probably the values to `In` are assigned outside of the *Mathematica*'s Main Loop although we can manipulate them by using top-level code. I accept your response.

Comment: The only little addition about your function for `$Pre`: it incorrectly work with inputs having `Head` `Sequence`. For making it perfect `HoldFirst` should be replaced by `HoldAllComplete`.